# Underwood Dudley trigonometry formula for a trisection

Tags: trigonometry

In his publications on trisectors Dudley claims that one construction is equivalent to the following formula:
$$\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{3}\right)=\frac{\sin \alpha}{2+\cos \alpha}$$
I was able to derive the triple angle formulas in Wikipedia, but when applying them to the above formula, I always end up with $\cos^2\alpha$ or $\cos 2\alpha$ instead of $\cos \alpha$.

Comment: The formula you have written is false when $\alpha =\pi$.

Comment: That formula is falso, of course. Otherwise, the construction that Dudley mentions would work, right?!

Comment: Thanks. Dudley wrote (A Budget of Trisectors, p. 25): His construction, which is the one in Figures 2.2 and 2.3, is equivalent to asserting that $$\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{3}\right)=\frac{\sin \alpha}{2+\cos \alpha}$$, something that could be verified by an intelligent trigonometry student. I interpreted this as meaning that the formula could be verified, not the construction...... Oh well, 4-6 hours wasted....